# How to write the constraints for a generic class

Tags: c#, generics

There is a generic class **XXValue** like this, where the Type T can be value type or reference type, e.g int, string, struct object

```
public class XXValue<T>
{
   public T DefaultValue;
}
```

And there is another generic class **XXAttribute**

```
public class XXAttribute<T>
{
   public T Value;
}
```

But the type T for **XXAttribute** should be the class or sub-class of type **XXValue**, so how to write the *where* statement for  **XXAttribute**? Which one is correct?

```
public class XXAttribute<T> where T : XXValue<T>

public class XXAttribute<VT, AT> where AT : XXValue<VT>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But the type T for XXAttribute should be the class or sub-class of type XXValue

Given this statement, it should be the second one.

```
public class XXAttribute<TBase, T> where T : XXValue<TBase>
{
    public T Value;
}
```

This specifies that the type parameter for `XXAttribute` should inherit from `XXValue`.  But since `XXValue` is also a generic type, you need to specify *its* type parameter in `XXAtribute` also, as `TBase`, and pass it along.

---

Alternatively (it's hard to tell given the scope of the question, but you could possibly) change how `Value` is defined:

```
public class XXAttribute<TBase>
{
    public XXValue<TBase> Value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Second would be correct as otherwise it is confusing for the compiler to know the value of T, where on one hand T is `XXValue<T>` and on the other hand T is `int`.

```
public class XXAttribute<V, T> where T : XXValue<V>
{
    public T Value;
}
```

Usage:

```
XXAttribute<int, XXValue<int>> attr = new XXAttribute<int, XXValue<int>>();
```